# How to multiply a tensor row-wise by a vector in PyTorch?

Tags: python, pytorch, tensor, scalar

When I have a tensor `m` of shape `[12, 10]` and a vector `s` of scalars with shape `[12]`, how can I multiply each row of `m` with the corresponding scalar in `s`?

Answer (score 37, accepted):

You need to add a corresponding singleton dimension:

```
m * s[:, None]
```

`s[:, None]` has size of `(12, 1)` when multiplying a `(12, 10)` tensor by a `(12, 1)` tensor pytorch knows to [broadcast](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/notes/broadcasting.html) `s` along the second singleton dimension and perform the "element-wise" product correctly.

Comment: Consider also `m * s.reshape((s.numel(), 1))`. This is easier to understand when reading code imo

Answer (score 3):

You can broadcast a vector to a higher dimensional tensor [like so](https://discuss.pytorch.org/t/how-to-broadcast-a-1d-tensor-with-a-4d-tensor/22976):

```
def row_mult(input, vector):
    extra_dims = (1,)*(input.dim()-1)
    return t * vector.view(-1, *extra_dims)
```

Answer (score 2):

A slighty hard to understand at first, but very powerful technique is to use Einstein summation:

```
torch.einsum('i,ij->ij', s, m)
```

Answer (score 0):

Shai's answer works if you know the number of dimensions in advance and can hardcode the correct number of `None`'s. This can be extended to extra dimentions is required:

```
mask = (torch.rand(12) > 0.5).int()  
data = (torch.rand(12, 2, 3, 4))
```

```
result = data * mask[:,None,None,None]

result.shape                  # torch.Size([12, 2, 3, 4])
mask[:,None,None,None].shape  # torch.Size([12, 1, 1, 1])
```

If you are dealing with data of variable or unknown dimensions, then it may require manually extending `mask` to the correct shape

```
mask = (torch.rand(12) > 0.5).int()
while mask.dim() < data.dim(): mask.unsqueeze_(1)
result = data * mask

result.shape  # torch.Size([12, 2, 3, 4])
mask.shape    # torch.Size([12, 1, 1, 1])
```

This is a bit of an ugly solution, but it does work. There is probably a much more elegant way to correctly reshape the `mask` tensor inline for a variable number of dimensions